# How to enable/disable a magnetic grid in Java

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, grid, jpanel

Here's what I need to do:
Make a grid where I can drag and drop elements. (already done)

My problem is I need to give the option to enable magnetic grid, such as the Windows desktop when you allign icons.

What type of item should I use with Swing ? (Jpanel, GridLayout)

Is there an easy way to make a magnetic grid without coding everything?
*I need to be able to place items wherever I want when the magnetic option is not checked.

Thank you guys

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider using a JLayeredPane, and adding as one layer a JPanel holding a grid of JPanels. When you want the grid functioning, then when a component is released over the GUI, the JPanel cell that contains your mouse pointer can accept the component and can perhaps center it using a GridBagLayout. When you want to place items in a free-hand way, then add them to a JPanel layer of the JLayeredPane that uses a null layout.